# whats wrong with my below merge sort code in python?

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

**merge sort**

it is showing error i cant able to figure out please help in merge sort,, It is showing out of index but i cant figure it out how please could anyone update and please help me?

```
def mergesort(a,low,high):
    if(low<high):
        mid=(high+low)//2
        mergesort(a,low,mid)
        mergesort(a,mid+1,high)
        merge(a,low,mid,high)
def merge(a,low,mid,high):
    i=low
    j=mid+1
    while(i<=mid and j<=high):
        if(a[i]<=a[j]):
            print(a[i])
            c.append(a[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            c.append(a[j])
            j+=1
a=[4,2,7,0,9,6,5]
c=[]
mergesort(a,0,len(a))
print(c)
```

`my merge sort algo not working`

Comment: The first problem is the index numbering.  You need both low and high to be IN the list, so do `mergesort(a,0,len(a)-1)`, but that's not the only problem here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VqmGXwpLqc&ab_channel=MichaelSambol

Answer (score 0):

After you fix the indexing, there are other problems.  "Mergesort" is supposed to do a sort in place, modifying the original list.  You're not doing that; you're trying to build up a new list.  That means you need to RETURN the list you've created, and use that in the next pass.

Then, `c` cannot be a global.  It's local to the "merge" function, so each call has it's own copy.  Finally, each merge step only processed part of the list.  You have to copy over the parts you aren't changing.  This seems to work:

```
def mergesort(a,low,high):
    if low<high:
        mid=(high+low)//2
        a = mergesort(a,low,mid)
        a = mergesort(a,mid+1,high)
        a = merge(a,low,mid,high)
    return a
def merge(a,low,mid,high):
    c = a[:low]
    i=low
    j=mid+1
    while i<=mid and j<=high:
        if a[i]<=a[j]:
            print(a[i])
            c.append(a[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            print(a[i])
            c.append(a[j])
            j+=1
    c.extend( a[i:mid+1] )
    c.extend( a[j:] )
    return c

a=[4,2,7,0,9,6,5]
c = mergesort(a,0,len(a)-1)
print(c)
```